# WCF RIA Services Silverlight 3.0

Tags: wcf, silverlight-3.0, service, ria

I have downloaded WCF RIA Services Beta from the following website: WCF RIA Services Beta for Visual Studio 2008 SP1

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=76bb3a07-3846-4564-b0c3-27972bcaabce&displaylang=en#filelist

But I am unable to add a reference to the following assembly : system.Windows.Ria.Data 
I searched at the downloaded location c:\Program files\Microsoft SDK's\RIA Services but i am unable to find this dll.

Would appreciate if you could point me what I am missing here.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the namespace system.Windows.Ria.Data is in System.Windows.Ria.dll. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ria.data.domainidentifierattribute(VS.91).aspx

Comment: Thanks for replying patrick. 
I was looking for System.Windows.Ria.Data, well after some googling I figured that this namespace has been removed.. http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/146774/326845.aspx

But now I am at the following problem, would appreciate if you could throw some light on this: 
I have removed the namespace system.Windows.Ria.Data and replaced it with System.Web.Ria.Data but getting following exception: 
The name 'RiaContext' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Can you update your question with the details of the error ?
It looks like you either using the context in the wrong side or the files wasn't generated

Answer (score 0):

John,
    RiaContext has been changed to WebContext. It can be found in System.Windows.Ria namespace.